# How to manage keyboard navigation a11y in IE11 when the page have iframe element?

Tags: iframe, accessibility, internet-explorer-11, section508, keyboard-navigation

#### Problem Statement

I have a html page which consist of iframe(where the content is loaded dynamically on navigation) and there are other elements e.g. buttons, fancytree, navigation controls etc.
**Keyboard Navigation using keyboard on first load:**
1. from url address bar to any children on the page
2. Keyboard Navigate inside iframe content(because one of the element moves focus to iframe content)
navigation works as expected.
**Keyboard Navigation after update in iframe content:**
iframe content is updated, after that pressing tab key, goes to IE11 tab and pressing it again, doesn't lead to focusing on any element.

#### Analysis

I have tried following:

1. Checked activeElement, pressing it again when the focus is on IE Tab, activeElement is pointing to iframe, but pressing it again, just moves the focus out of the page and it goes back to addressbar.
2. Checked the code base for tabindex property on iframe and other elements. On iframe tabindex isn't set. There are few elements e.g. skipcontent, exit button etc, where tabindex order is set.
3. Tried setting blur and focus event listener on body element, such that to move focus on desired element(doesn't work)
4. Tried setting tabindex for iframe, in this case surprisingly one of the page which consists of video, it gets focus and keyboard navigation works as expected, but other pages still don't get any focus.

Any suggestions on how should I go about solving this issue?

Note: I have tried to debug in Chrome, by installing couple of a11y extensions, but haven't figured out an extension, which can check keyboard a11y.

Comment: can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT The rendered code is using Apache velocity and other libraries, I will see, if its possible to extract and create a sample to reproduce the issue.